# Should a Finder Method be part of the Data Mapper, or part of the domain class?

Tags: oop, orm, datamapper

In Martin Fowler's Patterns for Enterprise Application Architectures book (page 229 in German, Lazy Load) he gives an example with this code:

```
public List getProducts() {
    if (products == null) products = Product.findForSupplier(getID());
    return products;
}
```

like you can see, the finder method seems to be part of the domain class Product. This confuses me a little bit, since I thought everything related to retrieving objects from *somewhere* (often a database, but business logic shouldn't care) should be part of the Data Mapper (PersonDataMapper) class. Probably I just missed something?

Comment: Since you are german, I'd also suggest buying http://www.phpdesignpatterns.de if you don't own that yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you gave is the *easy method* for Lazy Loading. Person is unlikely using a DataMapper. As Fowler states in the english book (201):

> Using lazy initialization is simple,
>   but it does tend to force a dependency
>   between the object and the database.
>   For that reason it works best for
>   *ActiveRecord*, *Table Data Gateway* and *Row Data Gateway*. If you are
>   using *Data Mapper*, you'll need an
>   additional layer of indirection, which
>   you can obtain by using a **virtual
>   proxy** [GOF].

As for *everything [...] should be in the DataMapper*, well.. yes, but also no.
What you should keep in mind when working with design patterns is *when to use them and when not*. DataMapper is not the Holy Grail. It's not the only way to do it. When your app is just a small and simple CRUD app living on the web, then the added complexity of a Data Mapper and/or using a Domain Model is likely not worth the effort.

In addition, design patterns are *generic* good practise approaches to common software problems. While you may be able to apply them to your *concrete* problems as they are given in a book, there is no reason to follow them religiously. If something in a pattern would overly complicate your problem solving, then *keep it simple*. Derive. Adjust. Solve the problem.

Comment: I agree with you, maybe a DataMapper pattern is really over-development in my case. But I try to develop now something for my little site, that will also be useful as soon as I have an idea for something really big/complex. Going to just add finders to the DataMapper as it sounds reasonable to me ;)

Comment: See, that's the point. Use it, when you need it. If you ain't gonna need it, leave it out. I know it is tempting not to, but it does not add any value to your app to have it now.